# Transaction doesn't get reverted when I add gas parameter in web3

Tags: solidity, web3.py

I have a function with modifier that I call through web3.py.
If I do this function call without using the gas parameter, like this:

```
MyContract.functions.preBid(100, 10, 0).transact({'from': accounts[0]})
```

it gets correctly reverted because of its input. But if I call this function using the gas parameter (which is necessary because otherwise, I would run into an out of gas problem later in the transaction) my function doesn't get reverted:

```
MyContract.functions.preBid(100, 10, 0).transact({'from': accounts[0],'gas': 50000000})
```

Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: I am not experienced with web3.py but when I checked documentation of transact it is mostly called like 
   MyContract.functions.preBid(100, 10, 0).transact({'from': accounts[0],'gas': 50000000})
So you have an extra curly bracket after from which is unneccessary
I think that "function is not reverted" does not mean it changed the state of EVM.
Could you please provide more detail? If it does not help you.

Comment: ah thank you! but that was just a typo in this post. And correct, it didn't change the state of the EVM, no events got emitted but it used gas. I just didn't get the usual error that the function got reverted

Comment: What kind of node are you connected to? (Geth, parity, ganache, etc) Also, can you post the solidity source? Technically, evm code can change behavior based on remaining gas, although it's rarely used.

Comment: I'm connected to Ganache. The solidity source code? I'm not sure if that is helpful without much context and I would have to post quite a lot. But what happens is, that preBid calls another function in the same contract and this other function has a modifier, which only allows it to be called once per AuctionID. That worked perfectly without the added gas parameter but now it just consumes gas, doesn't change the EVM and I don't get any kind of feedback if the transaction was successful or not